# Paging in the right way to import data in R from Cassandra

Tags: r, cassandra

I have a problem that is making me mad. I am trying to import data in R from Cassandra.

```
    library(RJDBC)
    library(glmnet)


     cassandra_conn <- dbConnect(JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",list.files("/data/data/LIBS",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),identifier.quote="`"),"jdbc:cassandra://ciccio01:9160/banza")

     name <- "sector"
     sect <- order_to_campaign[[name]]

     cl_imp_ <- dbGetQuery(cassandra_conn, paste0("select * from adv where order_id = '",sett[1], "'"))

     for(i in 2:length(sect))
     {
        print(sect[i])
        cl_imp_ <- rbind(cl_imp_ , dbGetQuery(cassandra_conn, paste0("select * from adv where order_id = '",sect[i], "'")))  
     }
```

Now, the first query works fine. But then, in the for loop, I always get a TimeOutException() and I can't understand why. I Googled everything, without being able to understand to what that exception is due. 
Finally, together with a colleague of mine, we thought that it might be due to paging problems in R. The way we solved this is writing the query in the shell, and then saving the data in another file and finally reading that file in R.

My question is: is it possible that this is the only way to do it? I think there must be a much easier way to solve this problem using very simple queries.

This is the schema of my table:

```
    CREATE TABLE adv (
    user_id text,
    order_id text,
    advertiser_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, order_id)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (order_id ASC);

    CREATE INDEX adv_order_id_idx ON mytable (order_id);
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, you are using a clustering column. In your primary key, *user_id*  is your partition key and *order_id*  is your clustering column. And you created an index on your table to be able to query over your clustering column.

In most cases, **indexes are not a good idea** !

Basically, NoSql database is not well designed to manage indexes over large table. So try to avoid that. A good alternative is to create sort of an index table by hand. Each time you insert in *adv*, dont forget to insert in *adv_idx* as well (in two different queries). It would look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE adv (
    user_id text,
    order_id text,
    advertiser_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, order_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (order_id ASC);

CREATE TABLE adv_idx (
    order_id text,
    user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id, user_id)
)
```

To retrieve information relative to *order_id* you query *adv_idx* and then foreach returned *user_id* you query *adv*. Cassandra dont have performance issue any more. Nevertheless the number of queries from the client side is bigger and it is longer to process.

Another solution is to add some redundancy :

```
CREATE TABLE adv (
    user_id text,
    order_id text,
    advertiser_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, order_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (order_id ASC);

CREATE TABLE adv_by_order (
    order_id text,
    user_id text,
    advertiser_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id, user_id)
)
```

Ok, your database is twice bigger now. But your performance is much better !

I tend to say that **redundancy is fine !**

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the problem comes from R paging because TimeOutException is a java exception thrown by the Cassandra service.

Could you give us further information :

- What is the schema of your table ?
- Do you have any clustering key ? If so, how much entries do you have in a partition ? (Too much entries or volume leads to TimeOutException)

Comment: I've added the schema of my table. Could it be more useful? Thanks!